# Xpath to Google Sheets - Specific dl-list content

Tags: html, google-sheets, xpath

I have this google spreadsheet which i use to scrape certain info from a bookstore:

- Title
- Author
- ISBN
- Price

They changed something about their website, before the info about the ISBN was in a unordered list (ul). They changed it to a description list (dl). now i tried fixing it myself but i really can't get the formula right in my google spreadsheet to scrape the right info. I can't just copy the xpath because the lists aren't the same for every book. so i need to specify which info i need with classes.

- [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iZ3PfF_dDtOxV4sDRYZY4Z93NRQiIZPvtgPWOG6xAko/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Bookstore Website](https://www.standaardboekhandel.be/p/het-bloed-van-olympus-9789000343041)

The info i need to scrape is the number in the dd element with class 'c-product-spec__value'

```
<div class="c-product-spec__rows" style="height: inherit;">
                                    <dl class="c-product-spec__row">
                                        <dt class="c-product-spec__label c-product-spec__label--collapsable">Productcode (EAN):</dt>
                                            <dd class="c-product-spec__value">9789000343041</dd>
                                    </dl>
```

Comment: So, where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1; "//dd[@class='c-product-spec__value']"); 4)
```

[image]

but on the other hand, it's in the URL so you can save some resources:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+$")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to retrieve informations.

```
//span[@class='c-product__detail__price--largest']      
//dl[@class='c-product-spec__row']
```

[image]

you can then apply index to fetch one information among the complete table

There is also another way : you can parse the json contained in a script

> {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Book","name":"Het bloed van Olympus","description":"Van Rick Riordans debuutserie Percy Jackson en de Olympiërs en het vervolg Helden van Olympus zijn wereldwijd 33 miljoen exemplaren in druk! Het bloed...","image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"https://media.standaardboekhandel.be/product-image?code=9789000343041&size=small"},"url":"https://www.standaardboekhandel.be/p/het-bloed-van-olympus-9789000343041","offers":{"@type":"Offer","priceCurrency":"EUR","price":"19.99","availability":"http://schema.org/BackOrder"},"author":[{"@type":"Person","name":"Rick Riordan"}],"publisher":[{"@type":"Organization","name":"Unieboek | Het Spectrum"}],"workExample":{"@type":"Book","bookFormat":"http://schema.org/Book","isbn":"9789000343041","name":"Het bloed van Olympus","url":"https://www.standaardboekhandel.be/p/het-bloed-van-olympus-9789000343041","datePublished":"2014-11-20","numberOfPages":432}}

[image]